# Windows Azure The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found

Tags: http-status-code-404, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm following [this](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/table-services/#create-account) tutorial which is about `Table Storage Service`. I'm using the emulator version of the tutorial which you can find at point 5 of paragraph "Configuring your connection string when using Cloud Services".

This is the code I pasted in the 'About' `ActionResult`:

```
public ActionResult About()
{

   // Retrieve the storage account from the connection string.
   CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
   CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

   // Create the table client.
   CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

   // Create the CloudTable object that represents the "people" table.
       CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("people");

   // Create a new customer entity.
   CustomerEntity customer1 = new CustomerEntity("Harp", "Walter");
   customer1.Email = "Walter@contoso.com";
   customer1.PhoneNumber = "425-555-0101";

   // Create the TableOperation that inserts the customer entity.
   TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(customer1);

   // Execute the insert operation.
   table.Execute(insertOperation);

   return View();      
}
```

At this line `table.Execute(insertOperation);` I get the following error message:

> StorageException was unhandled by user code The remote server returned
>   an error: (404) Not Found.

The project template I used was "Windows Azure Cloud Service". The next window that popped up, I only added "ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Role".

Anyone any idea what is causing this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does the people table exists in Storage area? (you can check from Azure management portal)

Comment: Hi, yea it seemed that i forgot to check if the table exists.

Answer (score 0):

I came here after getting the same error(Not found when .replace), but my case was different, I actually had people table but the problem with my code is that I was updating the Row key value. 
I think you can only update the other fields but not the partition keys or the row keys. Just thought of adding this to the answers in case someone else gets the same issue as me.